# How to create static pages programmatically from app on App Engine?

Tags: google-app-engine, sandbox

GAE is great. Everything becomes easy developing on it.

But recently I have found the need to create pages that can be served statically without changing my app.yaml and re deploying. Is this possible through the API?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. To change anything in the app, you have to re-deploy (which you could do programmatically).

Your options are serving dynamic contents, or putting the contents in the blob store (or some other CDS like Amazon S3), and serving it from there.